# Why can't I combine two SQL Server functions?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a database field with a URL that looks like this:

```
https://sub.chem.ratio.example/report/20073997621
```

I need to get the end of the string after the last `/`.

So I did this:

```
RIGHT(al.uri,charindex('/',reverse(al.uri),1)-1) AS ReportID
```

Which worked for most rows, producing this: 20073997621

but there are a few instances where I need to remove the word `redacted` from the end of the URL like this:

```
https://sub.chem.ratio.example/report/20073997621/redacted
```

So thought I could just combine both `RIGHT` and `REPLACE` like this:

```
RIGHT(REPLACE(al.uri, '/redacted', ''),charindex('/',reverse(al.uri),1)-1) AS ReportID
```

But the results are not what I expect.

The rows without `redacted` look good, like this:

> 20073997621

But if there was a `redacted` in there, it also trims off some of the report ID like this:

> 73997621

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Because you no longer want the rightmost characters. You need to do the replace on both parts of your expression.

Comment: @shawnt00 so do a `REPLACE(al.uri, '/redacted', '')` and a `REPLACE(reverse(al.uri))` here?

Comment: Well rather `reverse(replace(...))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, with or without the "redacted" should work:

```
DECLARE @url NVARCHAR(255) = 'https://sub.chem.ratio.example/report/20073997621/redacted'

SELECT REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(REPLACE(@url, '/redacted', '')), CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(REPLACE(@url, '/redacted', '')))-1))
```

Comment: Why do you need a `REPLACE`  twice?  thanks!

Comment: bc when you REVERSE, the first slash is tied to "/redacted" when really you want the first slash before "/20073997621"